# ansible - list with item index as hash

Tags: list, dictionary, indexing, ansible

I'm trying to add list element index as hash, preferably without using **with_indexed_items** because result is to be filtered later.

I'd like to convert this:

```yaml
vmware_disks:
- datastore: "datastores0"
  size_gb: 24
- datastore: "datastores0"
  size_gb: 397
  storage_policy: "vSAN standard cluster RAID-1"
```

to something like this:

```yaml
vmware_disks:
- datastore: "datastores0"
  size_gb: 24
  nr: 0
- datastore: "datastores0"
  size_gb: 397
  storage_policy: "vSAN standard cluster RAID-1"
  nr: 1
```

So far I was able to:

- using `"{{ vmware_disks | zip(range(0,2)) }}"`

  ```yaml
  [     
    {   
      "datastore": "datastores0",
      "size_gb": 24
    },  
    0   
  ],    
  [     
    {   
      "datastore": "datastores0",
      "size_gb": 397,
      "storage_policy": "vSAN standard cluster RAID-1"
    },  
    1   
  ]
  ```
- `"{{ vmware_disks | map('combine', {'nr':0}) }}"`

  ```yaml
  [
    {
      "datastore": "datastores0",
      "nr": 0,
      "size_gb": 24
    },
      {
        "datastore": "datastores0",
      "nr": 0,
      "size_gb": 397,
      "storage_policy": "vSAN standard cluster RAID-1"
    }
  ]
  ```

Please help me to combine both to get desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `set_fact` to create another dictionary and add the index in:

```yaml
- set_fact: 
    indexed_vmware_disks: >-
      {{ 
        indexed_vmware_disks | default([]) 
          + [ item | combine( { 'nr': index } ) ] 
      }}
  loop: "{{ vmware_disks }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: index
```

Then if you really need the dictionary to have the exact name it had before, you can just reassign it in another `set_fact`.

So an example playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    vmware_disks:
      - datastore: "datastores0"
        size_gb: 24
      - datastore: "datastores0"
        size_gb: 397
        storage_policy: "vSAN standard cluster RAID-1"

  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        indexed_vmware_disks: >-
          {{ 
            indexed_vmware_disks | default([]) 
              + [ item | combine( { 'nr': index } ) ] 
          }}
      loop: "{{ vmware_disks }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: index

    - set_fact: 
        vmware_disks: "{{ indexed_vmware_disks }}"

    - debug:
        var: vmware_disks
```

Would yield the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'datastore': 'datastores0', 'size_gb': 24})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'datastore': 'datastores0', 'size_gb': 397, 'storage_policy': 'vSAN standard cluster RAID-1'})

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  vmware_disks:
  - datastore: datastores0
    nr: 0
    size_gb: 24
  - datastore: datastores0
    nr: 1
    size_gb: 397
    storage_policy: vSAN standard cluster RAID-1

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I was hoping for "oneline" solution because it could be very useful in other lists, i.e. network interfaces. The one you proposed does the job, thank you.